# How to upgrade GIT to latest version in Visual Studio Team Services?

Tags: azure-devops

I am using online Visual Studio Team Services and GIT for a repository. I have the latest installation of GIT on my computer but when I push code to the repository I am getting an information

> "remote: We noticed you're using an older version of GIT. For the
>   best experience, upgrade to a newer version."

From the message I understood that I need to update the GIT in the Visual Studio Team Services to the latest version and I tried to find the way to upgrade but I wasn't able to find the option. Could you please help me to get the right direction? Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, Visual Studio Team Services is telling you that you need to upgrade your *local* Git client.  VSTS is safely running a custom Git implementation that you cannot modify.

If you're on Windows, visit https://git-for-windows.github.io/ and install the latest version.

Comment: I see the same problem when using the latest version of libgit2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48296823/visualstudio-com-thinks-latest-libgit2-is-old

Answer (score 11):

You need to upgrade your local git client. you should use the following command for upgrade git from the console.

for versions between 2.14.2 and 2.16.1

```
C:\> git update
```

for version above 2.16.1

```
git update-git-for-windows
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have chocolatey installed, run 
**>choco upgrade git**
in command prompt.

Comment: Remember to run in elevated/admin mode

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that VS is using MinGit:
https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.35.2.windows.1

You can update it using Nuget package called Git-Windows-Minimal:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Git-Windows-Minimal/