# Git pre-commit hook in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: git, visual-studio-2022

I'm trying to do some linting with dotnet format in a pre-commit hook in VS2022. The problem is that the pre-commit hook does not seem to be called when I use the VS Git gui to commit changes, even though it works when I use the command line. So even though the command line correctly cancels the commit as shown below, the gui erroneously creates a commit.

How can I get VS to actually use the pre-commit hook? I've seen it correctly use the pre-push hook.

pre-commit:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
#
# An example hook script to verify what is about to be committed.
# Called by "git commit" with no arguments.  The hook should
# exit with non-zero status after issuing an appropriate message if
# it wants to stop the commit.
#
# To enable this hook, rename this file to "pre-commit".

echo >&2 "Running git format"
LC_ALL=C
# Select files to format
FILES=$(git diff --name-only --diff-filter=ACM "*.cs" | sed 's| |\\ |g')
[ -z "$FILES" ] && exit 0
# Format all selected files
echo "$FILES" | cat | xargs | sed -e 's/ /,/g' | xargs dotnet-format --files
# Add back the modified files to staging
echo "$FILES" | xargs git add
echo >&2 "Deliberate failure"
exit 1
```

command line output:

```
C:\Users\<username>\source\repos\WpfApp1>git commit -m "Test"
Running git format
xargs: dotnet-format: No such file or directory
Deliberate failure
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently came back to this and was able to get it working. It seems that VS updates mean that xargs is now supported and I was able to use `dotnet format` instead of `dotnet-format`

Answer (score 3):

I've recently found (with my own pre-commit issues with VS) that Visual Studio implements it's own internal version of git (including `grep` and `sed`). Within that, xargs isn't allowed. Visual studio won't tell you it's failed and will just commit. Try removing out any xargs references from your code. Also, `dotnet-format` is also a custom installed program, so won't work via VS.

If you want all your stated functionality, switching VS to use system-installed git will likely work much better: [Configure Visual Studio to use system-installed Git.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43879501/configure-visual-studio-to-use-system-installed-git-exe/48395324)

To troubleshoot / get your code working I recommend testing out whether certain commands are even allowed in Visual Studio. Simply (temporarily) test out commands by putting code like the below in the top of your pre-commit file and try committing from Visual Studio:

```sh
xargs
echo "This outputs in VS git error window"
exit 1
```

[image: Visual Studio example output]